# Google-Login with capacitor-oauth2/Plugins.OAuth2Client.authenticate () does not work on Android device

Tags: android, ionic-framework, oauth, google-signin, capacitor

Initial Situation:

I need to implement a Google login with Ionic which works on a web platform as well as on an android device.

Therefore I use:

- Ionic 5.2.2
- Capacitor 1.1.1
- Capacitor OAuth 2 client plugin 1.0.0

With that setup I achieved already:

- Web-Login workes perfectly

Problem:

- Login in from an Android device doesn't work

I followed the steps in the readme from https://github.com/moberwasserlechner/capacitor-oauth2/blob/master/README.md

- I registered the plugin OAuth2Client in my app.component.ts
- I implemented a method googleLogin() where I call Plugins.OAuth2Client.authenticate() with OAuth2AuthenticateOptions

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { registerWebPlugin } from "@capacitor/core";
import { OAuth2Client } from '@byteowls/capacitor-oauth2';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("Register custom capacitor plugins");
    registerWebPlugin(OAuth2Client);
  }
}
```

home.page.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Plugins } from '@capacitor/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor() { }

  async googleLogin() {

    try {
      const resourceUrlResponse = await Plugins.OAuth2Client.authenticate({
        appId: "XXX.apps.googleusercontent.com",
        authorizationBaseUrl: "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
        accessTokenEndpoint: "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token",
        scope: "email profile",
        resourceUrl: "https://www.googleapis.com/userinfo/v2/me",
        web: {
          redirectUrl: "http://localhost:8100",
          windowOptions: "height=600,left=0,top=0"
        },
        android: {
          appId: "XXX.apps.googleusercontent.com",
          responseType: "code",
          customScheme: "com.xxx.playground.googleLogin07"
        }
      })
    }
    catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  }

}
```

On an device this code results in an error-message from Google:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pl2yo.png)

This is plausible. It seems to be that the method Plugins.OAuth2Client.authenticate() tries to do a web-based login where an android login is needed. Am I right?

If I make a call without the "web"-parameter like this...

```
const resourceUrlResponse = await Plugins.OAuth2Client.authenticate({
        appId: "XXX.apps.googleusercontent.com",
        authorizationBaseUrl: "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
        accessTokenEndpoint: "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token",
        scope: "email profile",
        resourceUrl: "https://www.googleapis.com/userinfo/v2/me",
        android: {
          appId: "XXX.apps.googleusercontent.com", //--> I tried both, android- and web-client key from the google clout platform console.
          responseType: "code",
          customScheme: "com.xxx.playground.googleLogin07"
        }
      })
```

...the method Plugins.OAuth2Client.authenticate() returns a blank error object --> {}

What am I doing wrong?